# Iterate through images (jQuery) for dynamic sizing/positioning (CSS)

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm building a jQuery script to size and position image elements on page load or resize. I'm using Bootstrap for my layout. I'm using a fixed height with CSS. Beyond development, I will not have control over the size or aspect ratios of the images.

I built a little script locally that gets the math and `if` statements right for images of different sizes and aspect ratios. Now I need to get it wrapped (I think) in a jQuery `each()` loop.

I tried a single loop wrapped around the main script which targets each element with a `.listing-box` class. Then I tried adding another (nested) loop to target the actual image inside. I end up with the first calculations being applied to all subsequent images. I don't know how to implement `each()` properly.

[JSBin (single image)](http://jsbin.com/yexog/1/edit?html,css,js)

[JSBin (multiple images)](http://jsbin.com/juxodo/3/edit?html,css,js)

HTML

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3">
        <a href="#">
            <div class="listing-box">
                <div class="listing">
                    <img src="http://placehold.it/600x400" alt="thumbnail" class="thumb">
                </div>
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.listing-box {
    width: 100%;
    height: 220px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.thumb {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

jQuery

```
$(window).on('resize load', function() {
    // get .listing-box width and height
    var boxWidth = $(".listing-box").width();
    var boxHeight = $(".listing-box").height();
    var boxAspect = (boxWidth / boxHeight);

    // get .thumb width and height
    var imgWidth = $(".thumb").width();
    var imgHeight = $(".thumb").height();
    var imgAspect = (imgWidth / imgHeight);

    // set some empty variables
    var newWidth,
        newHeight,
        mTop,
        mLeft;

    if (imgAspect < 1) {
        // image is VERTICAL
        // assign values
        newWidth = boxWidth;
        newHeight = newWidth * imgHeight / imgWidth;
        mTop = (newHeight - boxHeight) / 2;

        // use new values for inline css
        $(".thumb").css({
            width: newWidth + "px",
            height: newHeight + "px",
            marginTop: "-" + mTop + "px"
        });
    } else {
        // image is HORIZONTAL
        if (imgAspect > boxAspect) {
            // image is more wider than taller
            // assign values
            newHeight = boxHeight;
            newWidth = newHeight * imgWidth / imgHeight;
            mLeft = (newWidth - boxWidth) / 2;

            // use new values for inline css
            $(".thumb").css({
                width: newWidth + "px",
                height: newHeight + "px",
                marginLeft: "-" + mLeft + "px"
            });
        } else {
            // image is more taller than wider
            // assign values
            newWidth = boxWidth;
            newHeight = newWidth * imgHeight / imgWidth;
            mTop = (newHeight - boxHeight) / 2;

            // use new values for inline css
            $(".thumb").css({
                width: newWidth + "px",
                height: newHeight + "px",
                marginTop: "-" + mTop + "px"
            });
        }
    }

});
```

I know there are plugins out there for this, but I'd like to try this without any. I'm just stuck on looping.

Comment: Please show your `each()` attempt.

Comment: @isherwood I should have mentioned... I left comments in the JSBin (multiple images) JavaScript section where I placed my `each()` attempts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close. You do need to wrap the entire function in a `.each()` loop like so:

```
$(window).on('resize load', function() {
 $('.listing-box').each(function() {

    var boxWidth = $(".listing-box").width();
    var boxHeight = $(".listing-box").height();
    var boxAspect = (boxWidth / boxHeight);

    // get .thumb width and height
    var imgWidth = $(".thumb").width();
    var imgHeight = $(".thumb").height();
    var imgAspect = (imgWidth / imgHeight);

   // etc...
 });
});
```

However, if you simply do that, jQuery is going to, for each time it finds a `.listing-box` element, grab **ALL** `.listing-box` and `.thumb` elements and apply the your sizing logic to it. What you need to to target the particular `.listing-box` element that is currently inside the each loop and it's `.thumb` child. The way you do that is with `this`:

```
$(window).on('resize load', function() {
 $('.listing-box').each(function() {

    //Get the width & height for the current .listing-box element
    //within the loop
    var boxWidth = $(this).width();
    var boxHeight = $(this).height();
    var boxAspect = (boxWidth / boxHeight);

    // Get the width and height for the child of the current
    //.listing-box element that has the .thumb class
    var imgWidth = $(this).find('.thumb').width();
    var imgHeight = $(this).find('.thumb').height();
    var imgAspect = (imgWidth / imgHeight);

   // etc...
 });
});
```

**Note:** jQuery passes regular DOM objects through the `.each()` function, **NOT** jQuery objects. So in order to access the current element within the each loop as a jQuery object, you need to wrap it in the jQuery selector: `$(this)`.

It can get difficult to keep track of `this` with nested loops, so a best practice is to store `this` in a variable at the beginning of the function. So with those changes, your function should look like this:

```
$(window).on('resize load', function() {
 $('.listing-box').each(function() {

   //Get the current .listing-box element (and it's .thumb) 
   //that has been passed to the loop and store it in a variable
   var $box = $(this);
   var $thumb = $(this).find('.thumb');

  // get .listing-box width and height
   var boxWidth = $box.width();
   var boxHeight = $box.height();
   var boxAspect = (boxWidth / boxHeight);

   // get .thumb width and height
   var imgWidth = $thumb.width();
   var imgHeight = $thumb.height();
   var imgAspect = (imgWidth / imgHeight);

   // set some empty variables
   var newWidth,
       newHeight,
       mTop,
       mLeft;

   if (imgAspect < 1) {
    // image is VERTICAL
    // assign values
    newWidth = boxWidth;
    newHeight = newWidth * imgHeight / imgWidth;
    mTop = (newHeight - boxHeight) / 2;

    // use new values for inline css
    $thumb.css({
        width: newWidth + "px",
        height: newHeight + "px",
        marginTop: "-" + mTop + "px"
    });
   } else {
    // image is HORIZONTAL
    if (imgAspect > boxAspect) {
        // image is more wider than taller
        // assign values
        newHeight = boxHeight;
        newWidth = newHeight * imgWidth / imgHeight;
        mLeft = (newWidth - boxWidth) / 2;

         // use new values for inline css
         $thumb.css({
            width: newWidth + "px",
            height: newHeight + "px",
            marginLeft: "-" + mLeft + "px"
         });
     } else {
         // image is more taller than wider
         // assign values
         newWidth = boxWidth;
         newHeight = newWidth * imgHeight / imgWidth;
         mTop = (newHeight - boxHeight) / 2;

         // use new values for inline css
         $thumb.css({
             width: newWidth + "px",
             height: newHeight + "px",
             marginTop: "-" + mTop + "px"
         });
     }
 });

});
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation. Now I understand `each()` **and** `this` much better.